# Panasonic/Leica 15mm 1.7 vs DJI 15mm 1.7

Tags: lens

Is the DJI as sharp as the Leica on a OMD E-10 Mark II ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo.SE. What has your research found?

Comment: Used to have a Leica but now have the DJI - does not seem as sharp

Comment: There are many, many things that affect perceived sharpness.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a plethora of discussions on the internet, a comparison of the specs of both lenses, and published performance measurements of both lenses, it's pretty much obvious the DJI 15mm f/1.7 and the Panasonic/Leica 15mm f/1.7 are the same lens, made in the same factory, using the same parts. The only difference seems to be the branding.

Any differences in performance between individual copies of each lens can almost certainly be attributed to sample variation. Even if one had several copies of one branding or the other, there would be sample variation between each example.